# Prob. 1, Sec. 21, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: The induced metric and the subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Here is Prob. 1, Sec. 21, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $A \subset X$. If $d$ is a metric for the topology of $X$, show that $d | A \times A$ is a metric for the subspace topology on $A$.

My Attempt:

> First we note that as $d$ is a metric on $X$, so the function $d \colon X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ has the following properties:
>
> (1) $d(x, y) \geq 0$ for all $x, y \in X$; equality holds if and only if $x =y$.
>
> (2) $d(x, y) = d(y, x)$ for all $x, y \in X$.
>
> (3) (Triangle inequality) $d(x, y) + d(y, z) \geq d(x, z)$, for all $x, y, z \in X$.
>
> And, as $A \subset X$, so $A \times A \subset X \times X$ and the restriction 
>   $d | A \times A$ of the metric function $d$ to the set $A \times A$ is a function $ d^\prime \colon A \times A \to \mathbb{R}$ given by the formula 
>   $$ d^\prime  (x, y) = d(x, y)  \ \mbox{ for all } x, y \in A, $$
>   and this function $d^\prime$ also satisfies the above three properties (but only for all points $x, y, z \in A$). So $d^\prime \colon= d | A \times A$ is a metric on set $A$.

Am I right?

> Moreover, as $d$ is a metric for the topology of $X$, so the collection of all $\epsilon$-balls $$ B_d( p , \epsilon) \colon= \{ \ x \in X \ \colon \ d(x, p) < \epsilon \ \},$$ 
>   for all points $p \in X$ and for all positive real numbers $\epsilon$, is a basis for the topology of $X$. Therefore, the collection $$
> \left\{ \ A \cap B_d (p, \epsilon) \ \colon \ p \in X, \ \epsilon > 0 \ \right\} $$ 
>   is a basis for the subspace topology on $A$.
>
> Now we show that the topology induced by the metric $d^\prime$ on $A$ is the same as the subspace  topology on $A$.
>
> If $a \in A \cap B_d(p, \epsilon)$, then $a \in A$ and $a \in B_d(p, \epsilon)$   so that $d(a, p) < \epsilon$, and if we take $\delta$ to be any real number such that $0 < \delta < \epsilon - d(a, p)$, then 
>   $$ B_d(a, \delta) \subset B_d ( p, \epsilon). $$
>   So we also have 
>   $$ A \cap B_d(a, \delta) \subset A \cap B_d ( p, \epsilon). \tag{1} $$
>
> But we note that 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>  A \cap B_d (a, \epsilon) &= A \cap \{ \ x \in X \ \colon \ d(x, a) < \delta \ \} \\ 
> &= \{ \ x \in A \ \colon \ d(x, a) < \delta \ \} \\
> &= \{ \ x \in A \ \colon \ d^\prime (x, a) < \delta \ \} \\
> & \qquad \mbox{ [ note that here $a \in A$ and we also have $d^\prime = d| A \times A$ ] } \\
> &= B_{d^\prime} (a, \delta). \tag{3}
> \end{align} 
> $$
>   Then (1) takes the form 
>   $$ B_{d^\prime} (a, \delta) \subset A \cap B_d( p, \epsilon ), $$
>   in fact, 
>   $$a \in  B_{d^\prime} (a, \delta) \subset A \cap B_d( p, \epsilon ). \tag{2} $$ Moreover, the set $B_{d^\prime} (a, \delta)$ is a basis element for the topology induced by the metric $d^\prime \colon= d| A \times A$ on $A$.
>
> Thus we have shown that for any basis element $A \cap B_d(p, \epsilon)$ for the subspace topology on $A$ and for any point $a \in A \cap B_d(p, \epsilon)$, we can find a basis element $B_{d^\prime} (a, \delta)$ for the $d^\prime$-metric topology on $A$ such that (2) holds. So the $d^\prime$-metric topology is finer than the subspace topology.

Is this portion of my proof correct?

> On the other hand, if $a$ is any element of $A$ and if $\delta$ is any positive real number, then from (3) we have 
>   $$ B_{d^\prime} (a, \delta) = A \cap B_d ( a, \delta), $$
>   that is, any basis element $B_{d^\prime} (a, \delta)$ for the $d^\prime$-metric topology on $A$ is also a basis element for the subspace topology, which implies that the latter topology is finer than the former.

Is this portion of my proof correct and clear enough?

> In view of what we have shown so far, the subspace topology on $A$ is the same as the $d^\prime$-metric topology on $A$, where we define 
>   $$ d^\prime \colon= d | A \times A. $$

Comment: The second part seems excessive.  All that is needed to show is that B_d'(x,r) = A $\cap$ B_d(x,r) for all x in A, r > 0.  So the problem is how is B_d' defined?